# Connection failed issue during sudo apt update

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

When I try to run `sudo apt update` I get this error

[image]

My internet connection is OK. I don't know how to search this on the internet as this does not show the error. And when I run this `ps aux | grep -i apt`
 I get the below in the terminal.

[image]Can someone help me on this?

Comment: try to Ctrl+C to interrupt your `sudo apt update`, then `ping dl.google.com`. What does it show?

Comment: @Gryu ping works. `--- dl.google.com ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 11 received, 0% packet loss, time 10038ms`

Comment: @Gryu I tried several times.

Comment: @Gryu it runs for sometime and stops and shows "waiting for headers" then errors

Comment: Could you try other internet connection source to be sure, for example, your phone's wi-fi hotspot? Maybe something is blocking some sorts of requests or restricts them if their number is greater than specified. It could mean that someone changed your router's configuration or something else.

Comment: @Gryu You are correct my friend. I tried with my phone's hotspot and it did updated without errors. My other connection is also my other Android phone's hotspot. I actually used this connection today? What may be the reason? I can surf internet without any errors with that connection.

Comment: I don't actually know. But you could restart your phone with issue and try again. You could also try to check if usb-tethered connection works the same way. Phone's models and OS versions could differ. You could search for your phone's model wifi hotspot issues or watever if you connected through wifi hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Your network is OK. I think there is problem with your repositories.

Go to **Additional drivers** and go to **Other software** tab. And de-select any suspicious repositories and then try updating.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually answer, but could help to find out an answer. You could perform the next steps to find out the cause of the issue:

- Check if the issue reproduced using other type connection's type (USB tethering, Bluetooth tethering instead of wifi's hotspot)
- Change your Ubuntu's kernel
- Try to update Ubuntu on your friend's laptop:-)
- Install the same Ubuntu version to virtualbox and check if the issue reproduces
- Install an other version of Ubuntu to virtualbox and check

If the issue reproduced with different connection types, different Ubuntu kernels, different Ubuntu versions, different devices with different hardware configurations, then most probably the issue with phone's radio module firmware, phone's kernel, phone's firmware, phone's radio module itself. In this case you could try:

- Change your phone's firmware (maybe you could report this bug to your phone's product owner and wait for firmware updates)
- Change your phone's radio module firmware